Windows Server 2022 RDS Cal Licensing
I'm using Windows Server 2022, I'm actually playing with RDS Role.
I read that I can have 2 concurrent sessions without buying any RDS CAL (User/Device whatever).
What if I need 3 concurrent session? Can I buy one single RDS CAL or I have to buy 3 of them?

The 2 concurrent sessions without CAL are only available to Administrators, not to normal users. A regular user without server admin rights will always need a CAL.
(When the RDS Session Host role isn't installed yet, the server allows the free sessions by default, because it only allows admins to log in via RDP in the first place.
After the role is installed, if my googling is right, normal connections always consume a CAL and you must connect with the /admin RDP option to get a "free" admin session, and that option is again only available to admins.)
From what I remember, RDS isn't very strict when it comes to license accounting, so your home lab use might still work without any CALs installed, although you must still have the "RD Licensing Server" available.

A single RDS CAL in addition to your current two will be sufficient.
You will only need three CALs if you don't wish to start two sessions
as administrator. With three CALs you can have three non-administrator
users.
